# What is the verb in Πρωτεσίλαος?

Tags: ancient-greek, names, homer, compound-noun

Continuing in my chain of questions about Homeric names, I now understand that [Πενθεσίλεια is a "terpsimbrotos" compound](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/20867/406). This makes sense to me.

However, [Nagy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23065415) mentions this name alongside Πρωτεσίλαος, which seems to have the same -σι- between its two components. And I don't see how this one would work as a terpsimbrotos: the second component is presumably λαός, but what exactly is he doing to the people?

If this one really is a terpsimbrotos compound, what's the first component of it? Or am I misanalyzing this?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, LSJ think that "the name may be a corruption of *Πορθεσίλαος, cf. Cret. Πορθεσίλας and Πορτεσίλας". Seems implausible but maybe worth mentioning.

Comment: @TKR Interesting, so "pillager of the people"? I guess I could see it, though I agree it seems implausible.

Answer (score 1):

It may be one of the verbs derived from πρῶτος/πρότερος, such as πρωτεύω "be first among" or προτερέω "surpass". It's very possible that there was another verb like *πρωτέω formed from the same root which died out in the time since the name was derived; "surpassing the people" seems like a very reasonable terpsimbrotos name.

There's a strange, possibly-defective verb πέπρωμαι, "to have been destined", but it's not clear what "destined to the people" would mean, or what its present stem would be: this verb is only attested in the perfect and aorist.

LSJ suggest it might be a corruption of *Πορθεσίλαος, from πορθέω "pillage"; they cite Cretan forms Πορθεσίλας and Πορτεσίλας. But as TKR says in the comments, this seems somewhat implausible.

Whatever the true etymology is, it seems it wasn't clear to Homer; in Iliad 2.701-2 he implies it's from πρώτιστος "first" and ἅλλομαι "leap", since he was the first to leap ashore when the Achaeans arrived at Troy (or perhaps πρώτη ἕσις, "first sending-forth"). This lends credence to the idea that it might have come from a verb form that was extinct by that point…or maybe it was just a Homeric pun, since the root λαός would have been obvious to the author.